# Add an entry depending on existing entry in another table with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (X and Y) with the column E-Mail (column names: EmailX in table x and EMailY in table y). I want to add a column in table X which is filled with "yes" when the Email adress in table X is one of the Email adresses in table Y and "no" when the Email adress in table X is NOT one of the Email adresses in table Y.

How can I do this?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: See LEFT JOIN..

Comment: You shouldn't redundantly store a flag in table X. You can always check whether the email exists in table Y with `IN`, `EXISTS` or even an outer join in any query. If you don't want to have to write this in every query, then create a view for this.

Comment: How can I solve it with IN or EXISTS? Can you write me the code for the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store data redundantly in your database. As you can always check whether an entry exists in table y, you shouldn't add a flag to table x to indicate this.

Here is how to get the information with `EXISTS`:

```
select 
  x.*,
  case when exists (select * from y where y.emaily = x.emailx) then 'yes' else 'no' end
    as exists_in_y
from x;
```

The same with `IN` which I prefer for being simpler:

```
select 
  x.*,
  case when emailx in (select emaily from y) then 'yes' else 'no' end as exists_in_y
from x;
```

The same with an outer join

```
select 
  x.*,
  case when emaily is not null then 'yes' else 'no' end as exists_in_y
from x
left join (select distinct emaily from y) y on y.emaily = x.emailx;
```

If emaily is already unique in y, you can select from the table directly (`left join y on y.emaily = x.emailx` instead.

It's a matter of personal choice what to prefer. I go for `IN` usually, use `EXISTS` on conditions with `<` and `>`, and use a join when I want more than one field from the other table.

Comment: Is the CASE faster than IF solution ?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. `CASE` is standard SQL, `IF` is not. But `IN` /  `EXISTS` should be the fastest solutions usually when you want to look something up. At least they are the most readable :-)

Comment: The problem is speed for him. We talked about yesterday. So I finaly added a solution with PHP storing yes/no at INSERT. But I agree with you, not storing data is better.

Comment: I´m working on another querry atm and will return to it this "problem" this afternoon: Big thanks and thumbs so far for your support guys - you are awesome!

Comment: you're welcome... please vote for our solutionS if they are usefull for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column called "status", or something.

Set them all to no.

```
Update tableX set Status = "no"
where 1=1;
```

Then

```
Update tableX
set Status = "Y" where emailX in ( select emailY as emailX from tableY). 


commit;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it is exectuted after each INSERT, this will be very slow and not the best choice.

Comment: I don't read that, the title says "add an entry ..." but my english is not the best one, so in this case your solution is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with PHP that update directly the column 'inY' in X table at INSERT :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `X` (
              `emailX`, 
              `inY`
          ) VALUES (
              '$email',
              IF ((SELECT 
                   COUNT(Y.emailY) 
                   FROM Y 
                   WHERE Y.emailY = '$email' 
                   LIMIT 1
              ) > 0,'yes','no')
          )";
```

And result will be :

```
id    email             inY       ...
1     toto@toto.com     yes       ...
2     tata@tata.com     no        ...
3     titi@titi.com     no        ...
4     ...
```

But, maybe you can take the problem reversed !
It will be simplier to ask your database when you make a SELECT in the table X.

For example with 'yes/no' in results :

```
SELECT 
  X.id,
  X.emailX AS email,
  IF ((SELECT 
         COUNT(Y.emailY) 
         FROM Y 
         WHERE Y.emailY = X.emailX 
         LIMIT 1
  ) > 0,'yes','no') AS inY
FROM X
```

Instead of yes/no, you even can know how many times emailX is present in Y table with this query :

```
SELECT 
  X.id,
  X.emailX AS email,
  (SELECT 
     COUNT(Y.emailY) 
     FROM Y 
     WHERE Y.emailY = X.emailX 
     LIMIT 1
  ) AS inY
FROM X
```

The SELECT solutions are slower at execution on big tables.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner my opening bracket for the IF() statement was in wrong place, please let's retry...

Comment: The dataset is quiet big (about 300k rows in X and about 400k rows in Y): so it takes very long to do this request...It´s still not completed by now: is this normal?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner you must add indexes to your fields emailX and emailY like this : `ALTER TABLE X ADD INDEX(emailX); ALTER TABLE Y ADD INDEX(emailY);` this will increase a lot the speed of your queries.

Comment: I´ve done this already: but it´s still not completed: what´s wrong with it? Or is it normal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131178/discussion-between-meloman-and-absolutebeginner).

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner if you have PHP, you can try with the new solution I added in top of my answer, Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year.