# Add an entry depending on existing entry in another table with MYSQL Part 2

Tags: mysql

I tried to add an entry depending on existing entry in another table with MySQL: but the "solution" (I have from another question I asked before) is not working correctly on my data and I don't know why...

Here's the question I have the solution from:

[Add an entry depending on existing entry in another table with MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266733/add-an-entry-depending-on-existing-entry-in-another-table-with-mysql/41277659#41277659)

Here's my query where I create the necessary tables and import data:

```
CREATE TABLE `EMailImport` (user_id VARCHAR(20), `E-Mail` VARCHAR(150));
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/X/export.csv' 
INTO TABLE `EMailImport` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
DELETE FROM `EMailImport` LIMIT 1;
CREATE INDEX X ON `EMailImport` (`E-Mail`);
CREATE TABLE ABC AS SELECT customerID, ordernumber, `customersEmail`
FROM orders GROUP BY `customersEmail`;
CREATE INDEX Y ON ABC (`customersEmail`);
```

Here are the 2 queries I tried (where I used the solutions in):

```
SELECT ABC.*, CASE WHEN `customersEmail` IN (SELECT `E-Mail` FROM EMailImport) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' end AS `Did the customer ordered already?` FROM ABC;

SELECT ABC.*,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMailImport WHERE EMailImport.`E-Mail` = ABC.`customersEmail`) then 'yes' else 'no' end as `Did the customer ordered already?` from ABC;
```

Both are working but they show me "no" for every entry (what is not correct): where is the mistake/problem?

`Info`: the data typed of the columns in table ABC are:  customerID =int(10); ordernumber = varchar(50), customersEmail = varchar(255);

Comment: Does ABC contain valid data?

Comment: Yes, about 300.00 entries/rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this much simpler with a LEFT JOIN and COALESCE ?

```
SELECT ABC.*,
    CASE WHEN EMailImport.`E-Mail` IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
    AS `Did the customer ordered already?` 
FROM ABC LEFT JOIN EMailImport on EMailImport.`E-Mail` = ABC.customersEmail
```

And please please don't use terms like `E-Mail` with a `-` in the middle of it as column names. Please try to use all lower case for column and table names. And give meaningful names instead of `ABC`

An numerical columns like order number should be numerical (in this case int) and not varchar.

last but not least lengthy column alias like `Did the customer ordered already?` are rarely used. This is something that's done at the application layer at display time.

Comment: Seems like this is also not working: don´t know where the mistake is...

Comment: please never use the term 'Not working'.  explain clearly what happened.

Comment: ok, sorry- There´s a third column which is named CASE WHEN EMailImport.`E-Mail` IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END and all entries in this column are no (what´s not correct, because some of the EMailaddresses in table ABC definately exist in EMailImport)

Comment: isn't it a matter of adding the column alias? `Did the customer ordered already?

Comment: Convince us that the results are wrong by updating your question with some sample data

Comment: I think there´s a problem in the data import from csv: the data in the created table looks correct in my workbench, but when I select a specific email adresse which is in the table the system shows me no result instead of the one... does anyone know where the problem could be?

Comment: What you posted in your most recent comment should be a new question. **please make sure to post sample data**